# Add stock image to custom projection matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, gis, map-projections

Using the [custom map projection](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/custom_projection.html) code from the Matplotlib official documentation, how can I add an image of the world map that is also transformed into the custom projection? Similar to what I can do in Cartopy with `ax.stock_img()`

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: Speaking from a matplotlib expert's view, I see no point of you doing this